# finding .txt files with incomplete information in R

Tags: r, missing-data

I have a folder of .txt files. One of the columns in each .txt files is called "Row." (That's confusing, I'm sorry.) "Row" column contains values A thru H.

I'm trying to write something that I can run through each .txt file to check to see all the values from A thru H are present in the file. I want this function to tell me which .txt file is incomplete (missing some of the values). I don't have to know what it's missing... I just have to know which .txt file doesn't have all the values from A to H.

Is there a way to do this?

Thank you in advance~

**EDIT**

Here is a sample of the data I'm working with. This is from the first data frame in a list of data frames. So this is after I already made each .txt file into a data frame.

```
      row col TOF  EXT time green yellow red         worm call50    norm.red stage
1      A   1  20   20    0     2      0   0 1.922668e-02 bubble 0.000000000    L1
2      A   1  32   45  358     6      6   3 9.637690e-01   worm 0.093750000    L1
3      A   1  24   30 1185     6      1   0 2.246214e-02 bubble 0.000000000    L1
4      A   1 139  230 2433    39     49  31 1.000000e+00   worm 0.223021583    L2
5      A   1  27   23 2433     3      4   2 8.262885e-01   worm 0.074074074    L1
6      A   1  24   25 3946     3      4   3 9.077824e-01   worm 0.125000000    L1
7      A   2  40   55    0    30     46  29 1.000000e+00   worm 0.725000000    L1
8      A   2  31   34 2793     3      2   0 1.100591e-01 bubble 0.000000000    L1
9      A   3  37   42    0     8      9   5 9.996614e-01   worm 0.135135135    L1
10     A   3  89  172  562    28     38  20 1.000000e+00   worm 0.224719101    L1
...
648    B   1 124  160    0    11      8   4 9.999695e-01   worm 0.032258065    L2
649    B   1 125  211   47    13     11   4 9.999610e-01   worm 0.032000000    L2
650    B   1  65  112  141     6      4   3 9.404593e-01   worm 0.046153846    L1
```

Comment: Just so you know, editing is _strongly_ preferred to deleting a question that isn't going your way and re-asking it.

Comment: I did edit it but it got more confusing for people. So I thought it'd be better to rephrase my question entirely. Thank you for your advice though.

Comment: Still the same answer, why not just check the dimension of the data.frame once you have read it into R. Would those files missing any value from A to H not have reduced dimensions? A 96-well plate data, I assume.

Comment: Well, you're going to need to edit this question as well anyway, since all we have at the moment is an assignment, but no actual code on your part that we could give you feedback on.

Comment: For a list of data.frames, you can use `lapply(list_df, function(x) nrow(x)!=96)`

Comment: so I realized each .txt file has different number of rows for some reason... so is there a way I can get it to return which .txt files don't have all the values of A thru H in the column "Row"? For example, if a .txt file only has values of A thru E in its "Row" column, I would like to know which .txt file it is...

Comment: `length(readLines("yourdata.txt"))` gives the number of lines if that is enough, but if you need to check presesence of A-H, it needs some text processing. are you willing to share 5 lines of you .txt file?

Comment: `lapply(list_df, function(x) sum(x$Row %in% LETTERS[1:8])!=8)` will be TRUE for all those df's that dont have all A to H

Comment: @rmk, OP seems interested in checking that before loading to data frame

Comment: @Ananta: OK, in an earlier version of the question it seemed like the "list of data frames" was available. Given the task as defined now, it might need the files to be loaded anyway.

Comment: @rmk When I apply the line of code you suggested, I get a number of rows for each of the data frames in the list... do you think I copied it in wrong..?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. It should be `lapply(list_df, function(x) sum(LETTERS[1:8] %in% x$row)!=8)`, since you want to find which of A-H is missing. Changed to `x$row` base don your example above.

Comment: hmm, now your data became complex, what is different in first 6 rows of data, they are all A1, how do you know which plate it is. if you just care if A to H all are present at least once simply, length(unique(df$row)) should be 8

Comment: @Ananta Yeah.. sorry... that's why I had a hard time trying to explain my question. So each plate has rows A ~ H and columns 1 ~ 12, which are "row" and "col" of the columns.

Comment: I know each plate has A-H, and 1-12, but here, you have six A1, so it seems you already merged all of them without another ID, and it's impossible to tell where this row came from. probably you should start with the file that has 96 or less than that (for missing). I can count how many values you have foreach A-H and 1-12 combination with, `a<-data.frame(row=rep(LETTERS[1:8], each=12),col=rep(1:12, times=8))`
`b<-data.frame(a, c=runif(6*96))`
`library(reshape2)`
`dcast(b,row~col,length)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
ldf <- list(df1 = data.frame(row=LETTERS[1:8],col=1:8), df1 = data.frame(row=LETTERS[1:7],col=1:7))

> ldf
$df1
  row col
1   A   1
2   B   2
3   C   3
4   D   4
5   E   5
6   F   6
7   G   7
8   H   8

$df1
  row col
1   A   1
2   B   2
3   C   3
4   D   4
5   E   5
6   F   6
7   G   7


> lapply(ldf, function(x) sum(LETTERS[1:8] %in% x$row)!=8)
$df1
[1] FALSE

$df1
[1] TRUE
```

**BUILD**

Can also use: `names(ldf) <- c("file1.txt", "file2.txt")`

```
$file1.txt
[1] FALSE

$file2.txt
[1] TRUE
```

**UPDATE**

A nicer way would be:

```
lapply(ldf, function(x) all(LETTERS[1:8] %in%  x$row) & all(1:8 %in%  x$col))
$file1.txt
[1] TRUE

$file2.txt
[1] FALSE
```

Comment: That is awesome. Thank you so much! Another question though.. Is there a way it can show me the name of the .txt file that corresponds with whichever data frame that got "TRUE"?

Comment: you said you just had a folder of text files.. how does this work for your problem?

Comment: When you loaded your txt files as a list of data frames, you can name/tag the list entries with the names of the files in the folder. E.g., `names(ldf) <- list_of_file_names`. Then all subsequent computations would should the filenames (instead of df1, df2 in the example above)

Comment: Sorry I keep adding on questions... but would there be a way to test if a data frame has all of A~H in the "row" column as well as all of 1~12 in the "col" column??

Comment: @rawr Sorry my question has been confusing.. I'm applying this to a list of data frames that I have created by using the text files in the folder.. if that makes more sense? So this tests each of the data frame in the list

Comment: Just add `& sum(1:12 %in% x$col)!=12` to the condition within the function in `lapply`

Comment: @rmk so if I make the code of line you gave me into something else.. like this, datacheck <- lapply(r1.score, function(x) all(LETTERS[1:8] %in% x$row) & all(1:12 %in% x$col)), then is there a way for me to use an if statement or something to show me only the names of the ones that have been returned FALSE? (r1.score is the name of the list of data frames)

Comment: To get a vector out of this, you can `datacheck <- which(do.call("c", lapply(r1.score, function(x) all(LETTERS[1:8] %in% x$row))))`. Now `datacheck` would contain the locations of the list of files missing rows/cols. Accepting the answer would be appreciated!

Comment: That works great. Is there a way datacheck can return the names of those that DOESN'T have all the rows instead of returning the names of those that DO have all the rows??

Comment: Would this do the same job as what I described above??
datacheck <- which(do.call("c", lapply(r1.score, function(x) sum(LETTERS[1:8] %in% x$row)!=8 | sum(1:12 %in% x$col)!=12)))

Comment: @hj14 so why even *mention* the text files? jesus christ